# How do you reproduce "Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference " in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference
```

Anyone knows how to reproduce it?

Answer (score 4):

```
print $bar 1;
```

emits the error. you can see a nice explanation of what it means [on this perlmonks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=797845)

as explained by `splain`:

```
Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference (#1)
(F) A value used as either a hard reference or a symbolic reference must
be a defined value.  This helps to delurk some insidious errors.
```

Comment: what's different b/w hard and symbolic reference?

Comment: @R__ -- A hard reference is built like this: `$ref = \$scalar`. A symbolic ref is a string containing the name of another variable, like `$ref = "scalar"`. In both cases, you can get the referenced variable with `$$ref`. Symbolic refs are forbidden (for good reason) under `use strict 'refs'`.

Comment: @frezik =~ s/(?=forbidden)/mostly /; `$method` can be a symbol in `$o->$method()`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the simplest form:

```
say *{my $a}{SCALAR}; # OR say ${ *{my $a} };
```

Comment: The second is wrong. Gives "Use of uninitialized value in *scalar* dereference"

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -we '$x = shift; *$x = sub {42}; print $x->()'
```

This code prints 42 if called with ANY argument (incl. `''`), but gives the needed warning w/o args.

Comment: P.S. This is a living example now NOT to program in perl.